# Gutenberg Plugin Creation Structure and Files

Tags: reactjs, npm, wordpress-gutenberg

I recently refereed few Gutenberg compatible plugins. Example : https://github.com/HardeepAsrani/gutenberg-boilerplate. I am not able to get how following file is created

https://github.com/HardeepAsrani/gutenberg-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/block.js

I did an npm install and it provided me following files
[Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhYs1.png)

Also not getting how webpack.config.js file is run.

Can anyone explain me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently used that same boilerplate, and FYI, the `package.json` isn't well structured and has some old dependencies. I had to change some code in that file in order to get it to work. Here is my package.json:

```
{
    "name": "gutenberg-boilerplate",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=default webpack --watch"
    },
    "description": "This plugin add meta boxes in gutenberg's sidebar",
    "main": "src/index.js",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.0",
        "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
        "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^1.0.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
        "browser-sync": "^2.18.13",
        "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.0",
        "classnames": "^2.2.5",
        "cross-env": "^5.1.1",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
        "eslint": "^4.14.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^2.9.0",
        "eslint-config-wordpress": "^2.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.7.0",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
        "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
        "postcss-loader": "^2.0.9",
        "prettier": "^1.15.3",
        "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
        "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
        "style-loader": "^0.19.1",
        "webpack": "^3.10.0"
    },
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "license": "MIT"
}
```

Also, you have to add a `.babelrc` file in your root directory with the following code:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-react-jsx", {
      "pragma": "wp.element.createElement"
    }]
  ]
}
```

This ensures that the webpack config actually work.

And for answering your firs question. The file /dist/block.js is generated as result of the `webpack.config.js` output. Is is automatically created.

Here is my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
const path = require( 'path' );
const webpack = require( 'webpack' );
const ExtractTextPlugin = require( 'extract-text-webpack-plugin' );
// const BrowserSyncPlugin = require( 'browser-sync-webpack-plugin' );

// Set different CSS extraction for editor only and common block styles
const blockCSSPlugin = new ExtractTextPlugin( {
  filename: './dist/block.css',
} );

// Configuration for the ExtractTextPlugin.
const extractConfig = {
  use: [
    { loader: 'raw-loader' },
    {
      loader: 'postcss-loader',
      options: {
        plugins: [ require( 'autoprefixer' ) ],
      },
    },
    {
      loader: 'sass-loader',
      query: {
        outputStyle:
          'production' === process.env.NODE_ENV ? 'compressed' : 'nested',
      },
    },
  ],
};

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    './dist/block' : './src/index.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve( __dirname ),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  watch: true,
  devtool: 'cheap-eval-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /style\.s?css$/,
        use: blockCSSPlugin.extract( extractConfig ),
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    blockCSSPlugin
  ],
};
```

In order to run the configuration you just have to type in your terminal `npm run dev`, since that's the script defined in the `package.json` here:

```
"scripts": {
        "dev": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=default webpack --watch"
    },
```

I hope this help you to get started ;)

Comment: Thanks CubeInTheBox, I did more search and I just fix this 1 day back. But your post will surely help others who are just a beginner to React and Gutenberg.